# ¿Es correcto escribir "antiCebrián"?

Tags: ortografía, prefijos

Leía hace unos días:

> Así pues, una suerte de frente **antiCebrián** se ha impuesto finalmente en la Academia hasta el punto de que el antaño todopoderoso empresario de comunicación y magnate del grupo Prisa, editor de El País entre otros medios, apenas ha sumado un voto más (13) a los 12 que obtuvo la pasada semana en la primera votación.
>   <sub>[Los académicos se fiaron más de Muñoz Machado que de Cebrián para dirigir la RAE](https://www.eldiario.es/cultura/politicas_culturales/academicos-fiaron-Munoz-Machado-Cebrian_0_848665281.html), eldiario.es 21 diciembre 2018</sub>

Y ese *antiCebrián* me hizo alzar la ceja: ¡qué mal se lee una cosa así! Habría dicho que se escribiría *anti Cebrián* o *anti-Cebrián*, pero no todo junto creando una estructura tan extraña con una letra en mayúscula en medio de la palabra.

¿Es correcta esta grafía?

Comment: Hubiera molado que fuera correcta esa grafía *camelCase*, quizá cuando haya un programador en la Academia

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. **Lo correcto es *anti-Cebrián***, con guion entre el prefijo *anti* y el nombre *Cebrián*.

De la entrada del DPD de 2005:

> [**guion<sup>2</sup> o guión**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=cvqPbpreSD6esL3ahc).
>
> 1. Como signo de unión entre palabras u otros signos
>
> 1.2. Aunque normalmente los prefijos se unen directamente a la palabra base (*antinatural*, *prerrevolucionario*, etc.), **cuando el prefijo precede a una sigla o a una palabra que comienza por mayúscula, se escribe guion intermedio: *anti-OTAN*, *anti-Mussolini***. Cuando se desea unir en coordinación dos prefijos asociados a una misma palabra base, el primero de ellos se escribe de forma independiente y con guion, para evidenciar su condición de forma prefija y evitar, al mismo tiempo, la repetición de la base: *Se harán descuentos en casos de pre- o recontratación de servicios*.

Lo mismo se menciona en la [Ortografía de 2010:](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/z.cgi?t=0153685573486386194754281&s=1)

> Los prefijos se unen con guion a la palabra base cuando esta comienza por mayúscula, de ahí que se emplee este signo cuando el prefijo se antepone a una sigla o a un nombre propio: *anti-ALCA*, *anti-Mussolini*. El guion sirve en estos casos para evitar la anomalia que supone, en nuestro sistema ortográfico, que aparezca una minúscula seguida de una mayúscula en posición interior de palabra.

(mil gracias a [blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14069/blonfu) por [encontrarlo y transcribir la imagen](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49126799#49126799))